# Android FPS measuring on other apps

Tags: java, android, kotlin, frame-rate

I'm trying to find a solution for developing Android based app which will measure FPS same as Gamebench do. I was able to develop app which is showing the system FPS and not an app one (e.g. game app)

[Gamebench](https://docs.gamebench.net/docs/android-app-usage/requirements/) is doing it, so it must be achievable somehow. They are distibuting it through APK, so it's not ADB related. My goal is to have APK instead of connecting each phone and checking them up from time to time.

My approach is to send json data with device name and FPS count every second.

A user should be able to turn the app on or off.

Any ideas where should I start? Is it possible to do?

I have tried [Takt](https://github.com/wasabeef/Takt) or [Choreographer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer) but was only able to measure system FPS. Maybe I did something wrong there?